# SQL Join 3 Tables with specific fields

Tags: sql, join

my tables look like these:

```
**VBAK**
VBELN int
KUNNR int
dontwannahave1 int
dontwannahave2 int

**VBUP**
VBELN int
LFSTA int
dontwannahave11 int
dontwannahave12 int

**VBAP**
VBELN int
MATNR int
dontwannahave111 int
dontwannahave111 int
```

In the table VBAP there are 3 lines with a different value in MATNR. But the other 2 tables have only 1 line. At the end I only would like to have 1 line in this format:

```
VBELN LFSTA MATNR KUNNR
50001 1     1     1
50001 1     2     1
50001 1     3     1



SELECT *
     FROM VBAP
     LEFT JOIN VBUP
     ON VBAP.VBELN=VBUP.VBELN
     LEFT JOIN VBAK
     ON VBAP.VBELN=VBAK.VBELN
```

But how can I only have these 4 fields and forget all "dontwannahave" fields? And how get I the value of LFSTA and MATNR in each line.

Please see my SQLFiddle for further information:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8fbb6/1)

Comment: Just list the columns you want:  `SELECT VBAP.VBELN, LFSTA, MATNR, KUNNR`.

Comment: Oh my dear :/ this was too easy. But now I didnt get any value for lfsta and kunnr

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *, select the fields you want?

```
SELECT 
    VBAP.VBELN,
    VBUP.LFSTA,
    VBAP.MATNR,
    VBAK.KUNNR
FROM VBAP
    LEFT JOIN VBUP
        ON VBAP.VBELN=VBUP.VBELN
    LEFT JOIN VBAK
        ON VBAP.VBELN=VBAK.VBELN
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8fbb6/6

Comment: yeah :/ but now I didnt get any value for lfsta and kunnr and the order is wrong :/